# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Super User's [3rd moderator election](https://superuser.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Journeyman Geek] [image: Mokubai]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://superuser.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please bid a fond farewell to [veteran moderator Troggy](https://meta.superuser.com/users/2553/troggy), who has been a moderator since [election 0.66](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/welcome-new-super-user-moderators/) back in 2010. The ol' dragon-man has been too pressed for time to do much moderating of late, so he's decided to step down - please thank him for his service and wish him well in all his future burninations.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://superuser.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6511984921018368/0).

Comment: Congratulations to both of you, I'm sure you'll do a great job!

Comment: A very hearty congratulations to you both - welcome to the crew!

Comment: Congratulations to the both of you, you're both well respected and just as well-deserving. And I'll see you all next election! ;)

Comment: welcome to the team, get yer shields up for the stones are gonna come peltin'

Comment: Thank you for the kind words.  My announcement can be found at: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7988/troggys-beefy-arm-of-moderation-needs-a-break

Answer (score 25):

Congratulations, Journeyman Geek and Mokubai. I'm happy we have two new moderators ready to make Super User better for all.

As the third-place candidate in this election, I have to say that it was truly an honor to have come this close to getting elected and to have had such a great chance to serve the community we know and love. Over the coming weeks and months, I plan to spend a bit more time participating both on Super User and on Meta, answering more questions and working on the review queues.

I'll be honest with you: having grabbed the election data as soon as the election was over, I was almost heartbroken the moment OpenSTV reported the results. Nonetheless, it was a pleasure for me to participate in this election and I look forward to future opportunities to serve as moderator.

Comment: Honestly, I hope to see you're still hanging around when the next election comes about.

Comment: @Raystafarian: I most certainly will be.

Comment: Can't we make you honorary mod for a week or something?!

Comment: Given how many of you want me to be a moderator, I think we should talk with the incumbent mods who originally called the election and see if they have a use for another moderator. Stack Overflow and Super User both have at one point elected more moderators then were seats and SO [had appointed extra moderators between elections several times](http://stackoverflow.com/election).

Answer (score 13):

## 15 mins after elections and you've already seemed to have broken the site!!!!!!  Great job guys ;)

Honest congrats to Journeyman Geek and Mokubai.  They'll make great additions to the SU moderation team.