# Troggy's beefy arm of moderation needs a break

Tags: discussion, moderation

The smell of smoldering thatched roof cottages lingers in the distance.  A ♦ seems to be newly absent from those old dragon scales.

As part of the [2014 SuperUser moderator election](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7983/2014-community-moderator-election-results) coming to a close, I will be stepping down from my role as a moderator.  Due to changing personal schedules, my free time to moderate has been reduced significantly and it would be best to take a much needed break from my duties.

I am honored to have been part of the beginning of Super User and helping shape the website over the last 4.75 years. Much thanks go out to the many people who have dedicated countless hours to making this website a success.  This in no way is me leaving the website, it is just reducing my responsibilities at this time.  I still have lots of IT knowledge to contribute and love helping keep the site running smoothly.  If my time opens up again, maybe a future community election will grant my beefy arm of moderating once again.

I have nothing but good things to say about the current moderator team and congrats to our newest moderators.  Remember to use your new powers wisely as the community is watching.

Everyone sing with me as I pass the ♦ on! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoARQRCvpQU

Comment: Best wishes to you, thanks for efforts in keeping [su] clean :)

Comment: Thanks for everything! Also, if you could let us know which nation's countryside you'll be burninating on your vacation so we can all avoid it, that would be great.

Comment: I'll miss the smell of burninating posts left behind after a rampage. Thanks for everything you've done!

Comment: Look for an email from me, we'd like to send you something .... let's just say ... special.

Comment: You might want to update your about me ;)

Comment: +1,000 mystery points for that video

Answer (score 38):

Troggy! One of the early, the few.. the proud...

### THE BURNINATED

[image: plush trogdor]

It's been an honor to serve with you.

And Super User will always have a special place in my heart. A place [reserved for plush things](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/)...

Comment: Need a link to buy that Trogdor! I so need one!

Answer (score 5):

Troggy, thank you for your valiant service to Super User. As one of Super User's first moderators, you've done an outstanding job keeping the site clean during your tenure. We miss you, and we hope to see you continue to contribute when time permits.